# MySQL Adding columns together

Tags: mysql, sql

Quick MySQL problem.

I'm wanting to add multiple columns (column 2) together based one column (column 1) being checked to ensure they hold matching values

Example

Column 1

```
Team 1     
Team 2      
Team 3       
Team 1    
Team 3   
Team 2
```

Column 2

```
 1
 2
 3 
 1
 2
 3
```

Column 3 (Calculated based on the Values in Column 1 matching)

```
 2 (Team 1)
 4 (Team 2)
 6 (Team 3)
```

Of course I will begin by doing the following select statement:

```
SELECT Column 1, Column 2 FROM table WHERE ???
```

After the where is when I don't know what comes next to add the columns together based on the first column holding the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you just need a simple sum and group by. But I think in your example, Team 2 should have a total of 5, not 4.

```
SELECT column1,sum(column2) FROM table
group by column1
```